# SQL error - Msg 156, Level 15, State 1 : i cannot find any syntax error, please refer below code

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
USE [RSConnect]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[spTakeStudiesToMigrate]    Script Date: 05/04/2016 16:24:22 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spTakeStudiesToMigrate]
 (@RecordCount AS INT)
AS
BEGIN   
update tblDaMiSource 
set TransferStatus = 5
from (SELECT TOP (5) s.UIDStudy 
     FROM tblDaMiSource s WITH(NOLOCK) 
     WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT d.UIDStudy    
                        FROM tblDaMiDestination d WITH(NOLOCK) 
                        WHERE d.UIDStudy=s.UIDStudy and s.InstanceCount >= d.InstanceCount)
     AND  TransferStatus=2)

END
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a table aliases after the subquery . . . and to use the alias in the update:

```
update toupdate 
    set TransferStatus = 5
from (SELECT TOP (5) s.UIDStudy 
      FROM tblDaMiSource s WITH (NOLOCK) 
      WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT d.UIDStudy    
                        FROM tblDaMiDestination d WITH (NOLOCK) 
                        WHERE d.UIDStudy = s.UIDStudy and s.InstanceCount >= d.InstanceCount) AND
           TransferStatus = 2
     ) toupdate;
```

`NOLOCK` is a dangerous option in a database where tables are being modified.  This is especially true in an `update` statement.  I would suggest that you need Aaron Bertrand's advice [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3172/avoid-using-nolock-on-sql-server-update-and-delete-statements/).